# Redirect to another page instead of index.php through htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

When first time load the page instead of index page it should redirect to another page.
After that when we clicked on home page then it will redirect to home page. I have done through htaccess.
And I wanted to open database link also so I put below code.

DirectoryIndex inventory.php

```
< IfModule mod_rewrite.c >
  RewriteEngine on
  Rewriterule ^mega_dados/.*$ - [PT]
</IfModule >
```

Above code is working only for first time page load but rewrite rule is not working. If I'll comment first line then rewrite rule is working but directory index is not working. But I wanted both. How can I resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you need exactly, i use cookies to redirect you at first visit.
By the first visit, index.php will not find a cookie and goes to start.php

**index.php:**

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['MYcookie'])) {
        header("Location: ./start.php");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

**start.php**:

```
<?php 
  if (!empty($_POST['waarde'])) 
  {  
        setcookie ('MYcookie', 'yes', time() + 3600);
        header("Location: ./index.php");
        exit();
  }
?>

      <form method="post" action="">
      <input type="radio" name="waarde" value="1" checked="checked"><b>YES</b>
      <input type="radio" name="waarde" value="0"><b>NO</b>
      <input class="mybuttons" type="submit" value="ACCEPT">
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This on .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.example\.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.{htm|html|php)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.(htm|html|php)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```